# Drive.Drives.listでrestrictionsの値を取得または設定したい

Tags: google-apps-script

`Drive.Drives.list({pageToken:pageToken, maxResults:100, useDomainAdminAccess:true});`
で取得される戻り値で、`id` や `name` の値は取得できたのですが、`restrictions` がどうしても取得できず設定もできません。
どのようにすれば取得や設定ができますでしょうか。

---

Tanaike様、ご回答ありがとうございました。
取得はできました。
さらにお教えいただきたいことがありましたが、コメントでの返信では文字数足りなたかったため、こちらに記載させていただきます。

同様に`restrictions`を設定したいんですが、下記のパターンでいくつか`Drives.update`を試してみましたがうまくいきません。
申し訳ありませんが設定方法も教えていただけますでしょうか。

1の場合、以下のエラーになります。

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: 次のエラーが発生し、drive.drives.update の呼び出しに失敗しました: The requesting user does not have the administrator privilege required to manage the shared drive 0ADwtxWXOI0f9Uk9PVA.
```

2の場合、無視されたような状態です。

試したコードは以下の通りです。

```
    // 1
    var updateResources = {
      useDomainAdminAccess: true,
      name: "新名称",
      restrictions: {
        adminManagedRestrictions: true,
        domainUsersOnly: true,
        driveMembersOnly: true,
        copyRequiresWriterPermission : true
      },
      fields: "items(name,restrictions)"
    }; 
    var res_update = Drive.Drives.update(updateResources, driveID);

    // 2
    var updateResources = {
      useDomainAdminAccess: true,
      name: "新名称",
      fields: "items(name,restrictions)"
    }; 
    var updateOptions = {
      restrictions: {
        adminManagedRestrictions: true,
        domainUsersOnly: true,
        driveMembersOnly: true,
        copyRequiresWriterPermission: true
      }
    };
    var res_update = Drive.Drives.update(updateResources, driveID, updateOptions);
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

`Drive.Drives.list`では、デフォルトとして、`id, name, kind`のみが返されるようです。そのため、`restrictions`を取得するためには`fields`を使用する必要があります。今の場合、全てのプロパティを取得するか、特定のプロパティをを取得するか選択することができます。

#### 全てのプロパティを取得する場合

```
Drive.Drives.list({ pageToken: pageToken, maxResults: 100, useDomainAdminAccess: true, fields: "*" });
```

#### 特定のプロパティをを取得する場合

```
Drive.Drives.list({ pageToken: pageToken, maxResults: 100, useDomainAdminAccess: true, fields: "items(name,restrictions,id),nextPageToken" });
```

- この場合、`name,restrictions,id,nextPageToken`が返されます。

#### Reference

- [Drives: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/drives/list)

Comment: 取得はできました。ありがとうございました。